# Node.js emit data containing array?

Tags: node.js, events

I'm having problems figuring out how to stringify an array so that I can emit it to the clients connected to my node.js server.

All I'm trying to do is emit an array of the users connected to the server.  It's an array of objects that just have an id, name, and a few other bits of information.

I've tried to use **var users = Buffer.from(playerList);**
then in for my emit code:

```
var data = { players: users.toJSON() }
socket.emit('playerData', data);
```

but I keep getting a Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded error.
Thank you to anyone who read this

Comment: Normally, you should not need serialize/deserialize (i.e. stringify/parse) your data when sending them through socket. Just send your array. Can you show a simple example of server code and client code that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I would guess that your `users` array contains objects that have circular references.  You can't convert circular references to JSON.  You have to remove properties from your objects to remove any circular references.

Comment: @raphaMex I'm trying to post the code but having trouble indenting it correctly for stackoverflow..

Comment: @jfriend00 there was an error about circular references but I don't understand what that means...

Comment: Well, you'll have to show us what's in your `users` array for us to help more specifically.  But, a circular reference is when object A has a property which points a B which has a property which points at A (or there could be more than just two objects in the circular chain).  When code tries to "flatten" that structure by traversing it to generate JSON, it gets in an infinite loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 I appreciate that explanation I understand now.  I'll try to get this indentation correct.